# A Confusing Binary Encoding Result of C++ Double Number

Tags: c++, encoding, double

I know that IEEE double format gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. Converting a decimal number with more than 17 significant digits to double type will encounter precision loss.For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

void showEncodeOfDouble(unsigned char* db){

    const int ByteLength=8; 
    for(int i=ByteLength-1;i>=0;i--)    
        printf(" %.2x",db[i]);

    printf("\n");

}


int main(){
    //2^64=18446744073709551616

    double d1=18446744073709551616.0;   //20bit Significant,Precision Loss                          
    printf("%f\n",d1);                      
    showEncodeOfDouble((unsigned char*)&d1);

    return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
18446744073709552000.000000
43 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

After converting, the original 20 significant decimal bits are cut to only 17.My quesion is:

```
            Why the encoding result is 43 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00?
```

I refered to the encoding stander of double type and found that this stands for (-1)^0*2^64*1=2^64, I wonder why such an encoding is printed out as 18446744073709552000.000000.

Comment: Many decimal numbers with fewer than 16 significant digits cannot be represented exactly in double, such as 0.1 and 1e100. In general, a good library will give you the double closest to your decimal number, but there often will not be one that is exactly equal to it.

Comment: Thanks, Patricia. Yeah,generally a lot of decimal numbers cannot be represented by binary numbers exactly, but I just wonder how C++ translate 43 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 into 18446744073709552000.000000 from a decoded view.

Comment: The exact value corresponding to 43 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 is 18446744073709551616. I don't know the specific rules for your printf, but many libraries shorten their output by default, to avoid printing large numbers of arbitrary digits. The value you got is the decimal number with the fewest significant digits of all that would convert back to your double, so it is quite a reasonable choice for printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact value corresponding to `43 f0 00 00 00 00 00 00` is `18446744073709551616`. I don't know the specific rules for your `printf`, but many libraries shorten their output by default, to avoid printing large numbers of arbitrary digits.

For example, the closest double to `1e100` has exact value `10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104`. This is generally not what one would want to see on printing 1e100. Most of the digits have more to do with details of floating point representation than with its practical use.

The value you got, `18446744073709552000.000000`, is the decimal number with the fewest significant digits of all that would convert back to your double, displayed with 6 digits after the decimal point, which is the default for `printf` `%f` so it is quite a reasonable choice for formatting it.